# MVVM Light toolkit tombstoning + DispatchHelper

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I'm using the DispatcherHelper from MVVM light in a NotifyPropertyChanged method in my ViewModel to marshal calls to the UI thread. 
In my Application_Launching I initialize the Dispatcher like so:

```
DispatcherHelper.Initialize();
```

I also added the same to Application_Activated

When the  app tombstones  I save my VM to the "State" dictionary. When the app reactivates from tombstoned state the platform seems to be first performing a deserialization of my ViewModel before firing Application_Activated. As part of the deserialization the properties of the ViewModel are set which in turn calll the NotifyProperyChanged method in the view model. This in turn invokes the DispatcherHelper but since the "Initialize" method has not been invoked MVVM Light throws a "null reference exception"

So the question is where do I make the call to DispatcherHelper.Initialize() here.

**EDIT 1**
I noticed that if I persist my VM in the "Application_Deactivated" handler

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State[viewModelKey] = ViewModel;
```

and then go back to the app to reactivate it, I see the following calls in the "call stack view" with "Show External code" enabled"

```
Microsoft.Phone.dll!Microsoft.Phone.Shell.StreamPersister.Deserialize(byte[] blob, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Type> knownTypes, ref System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,object> dictionary) + 0x20 bytes   

Microsoft.Phone.dll!Microsoft.Phone.Shell.StreamPersister.Load(Microsoft.Phone.Shell.Interop.ShellPageManager shellPageManager, string key, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Type> knownTypes, ref System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,object> dictionary) + 0x28 bytes  

Microsoft.Phone.dll!Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.FireActivated(bool isExecutionContextPreserved) + 0x30 bytes  
Microsoft.Phone.Interop.dll!Microsoft.Phone.Execution.NativeEmInterop.FireOnResume(bool isExecutionContextPreserved) + 0xc bytes
```

These calls are not present if I do not add my ViewModel to the State dictionary

**EDIT 2:**
If I replace the call to DispatchHelper and replace it with the standard Dispatcher.BeginInvoke then the problem goes away.

CHANGE 
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
(
                () =>
                {
        //do whatever
        }
)

TO THIS
DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI
(
        () =>
                {
        //do whatever
        }
)

Comment: The values you write to the applciation state are not auomatically deserialized. When/where are you reloading the vm from the values saved in State?

Comment: It sounds odd to me that updating a property which calls NotifyPropertyChanged invokes a call to DispatcherHelper. If the DispatcherHelper is in the property setter, you should pull it out. You shouldn't need a call to DispatcherHelper when setting a property. Your xaml element should be bound to the property. Could you post your code so we can see what is going on?